# Cannot create an array within a class in Xcode using Swift

Tags: arrays, xcode, class, swift

I'm trying to create an array within my swift class in Xcode 6 beta 4 but I get the following error:

Swift Compile Error 'Level1.Type' does not have a member named 'someInts'

Here is my code

```
import SpriteKit

class Level1: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
    var someInts = [Int]()
    var message = "someInts is of type [Int] with \(someInts.count) items."
}
```

Adding the same variable declarations into a Swift playground does not produce this error.

What am I doing wrong here?

I'm trying to create an array within my class that can hold objects of type Int

Regards

Answer (score 3):

This issue is with the second variable. You can't assign a property a value that depends on another property inline. You can use a computed property though.

```
class Level1: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
    var someInts = [Int]()
    var message: String {
        return "someInts is of type [Int] with \(someInts.count) items."
    }
}
```